# The difference between "for item in list L" and "for item in list L[:]"

Tags: python, list, for-loop

What causes the difference of these two lists?

[image]
[image]

Comment: just execute `print j` and `print l` after for loop. you'll see difference. or, use this (http://www.codeskulptor.org/viz/index.html) to visualize what is happening.

Comment: I got it ! Thanks for all of you :D